# Possible to combine logical and position indexing in data.table?

Tags: r, indexing, data.table

I am trying to go through a data.table by group to assign value to each row conditionally inside each subgroup. I can select the rows I want but I cannot update the variable of interest in the rows that I selected.

I think this may be due to the fact that I have to slice the data.table twice. I am working with a `data.table` called `dt`, which has columns `group`, `center`,`date` and `var`. The goal here is to match the value of `var` of non-center records aka `center==0` to their closest (in terms of date difference) center records where `center==1`. Suppose `i` is the positional index of the row and I want to update record based on conditional filtering and then searching on `date` within the subgroup `gp`.

```r
dt[group == gp][i, var:= "new value"]
```

But when I run

```r
dt[group == gp][i, var]
```

The variable `var` seems unchanged aka returns `"old value"`.

## Additional information

The above command is inside a for loop, perhaps I am not using the best practice here. I would appreciate it if someone shares his/her opinion on the following for loop. Thanks.

```r
for( gp in unique(dt$group)){
  tmp = dt[group==gp]
  for( i in 1:nrow(tmp)){
  new_val = tmp[center==1][which.min(abs(tmp[i, date]-tmp[center==1, date]),var]

  dt[group == gp][i, var:= new_val] 
 }
}
```

I am aware of `set` and `.by` in data.table. But I do not know how to easily apply a conditional search function to each subgroup with `dt[, j=somefunction ,by=group]` syntax. Maybe I could put a sapply on `.SD` but is it much faster than a for loop? Is the gain in performance worth the loss in readability?

## Edit

In the comment section below I found the trick to combine logical and position indexing in data.table at the same time:

`dt[which(group == gp)[i], var := new_val]`

The question about whether using a for loop is a good idea still remain unanswered. Any inputs will be appreciated!

## Example

Suppose the original dt (sorted by group and date) looks like the following:

```r
group center  date     var
  1     0     10-01    NA
  1     1     10-02    val1
  1     0     10-03    NA
  1     1     11-05    val2
  2     1     10-02    val3
```

I want the updated dt to be:

```r
group center  date     var
  1     0     10-01    val1
  1     1     10-02    val1
  1     0     10-03    val1
  1     1     11-05    val2
  2     1     10-02    val3
```

Let's say we have about 10,000 groups here and each group could have up to 1000 rows.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Thanks for the comment! This trick works haha.

Comment: @markus example updated for the second part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, you might want to consider using the rolling join as follows:

```
dt[center==0L, var := dt[center!=0L][.SD, var, on=.(group, date), roll="nearest"]]
```

explanations:

1. `dt[center==0L` filters the rows to be updated.
2. `var :=` tells `data.table` this is the column to be updated.
3. `dt[center!=0L]` filters for rows where center is not 0.
4. `dt[center!=0L][.SD, on=.(group, date)]` left joins the rows from step 1 (`.SD`) with those from step 3 and `, var,` selects this column as the output.
5. see `?data.table` for the help on `roll` argument. When `roll='nearest'`, it finds the nearest `date` in the join. Note that the rolling key should always be the last element in `on` argument.

output:

```
   group center       date  var
1:     1      0 2018-10-01 val1
2:     1      1 2018-10-02 val1
3:     1      0 2018-10-03 val1
4:     1      1 2018-11-05 val2
5:     2      1 2018-10-02 val3
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("group center  date     var
1     0     2018-10-01    NA
1     1     2018-10-02    val1
1     0     2018-10-03    NA
1     1     2018-11-05    val2
2     1     2018-10-02    val3")
dt[, date := as.Date(date, format="%Y-%m-%d")]
```

Comment: Hi, this solution works for the posted example! Do you know where I can read more (with examples) on `roll` other than the descriptions in ?data.table ?

Comment: Or could you add some explanations for/ break down this one-line syntax? It would be much appreciated!

Comment: you might want to start with the data.table vignettes first? then maybe search for data.table rolling joins online. a helpful blog: https://www.r-bloggers.com/understanding-data-table-rolling-joins/